# Ошибка при конвертации BSTR в QString

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, типы-данных, конвертация

У меня есть функция, которая делает выборку по WMI, вот пример - https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aa390422(v=vs.85).aspx.
Всё работает, если я беру поля типа string или uint64, но если поле типа uint32 или uint16, то при попытки их конвертации из BSTR в QString методом QString::fromStdWString вылетает ошибка. Вот здесь можно посмотреть типы полей - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394102(v=vs.85).aspx.

Сама функция:

```
...
while (spEnumerator.get())
        {
            HRESULT hr = spEnumerator.get()->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1,
                &pclsObj, &uReturn);

            if(0 == uReturn)
            {
                break;
            }

            auto deleter = [](IWbemClassObject* p) { p->Release(); };
            std::unique_ptr<IWbemClassObject, decltype(deleter)> spclsObj(pclsObj, deleter);

            VARIANT vtProp;

            for (auto k : field_caption)
            {
                spclsObj.get()->Get(reinterpret_cast<LPCWSTR>(k.first.utf16()), 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
                records.enqueue(QPair<QString, QString>(k.second, QString::fromStdWString(vtProp.bstrVal)));
            }

            VariantClear(&vtProp);
        }
...
```

filed_caption - это пары типа Имя_поля, расшифровка, пример пары: "UserName" "Имя пользователя"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё оказалось банально, если возвращаемое значения типа `uint`, то вместо `vtProp.bstrVal` надо написать `vtProp.intVal`, странно, что я сразу не заметил этого. Вот обновлённый вариант:

```
    for (auto &k : field_caption)
            {
                wchar_t* wString=new wchar_t[4096];
                MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, std::get<0>(k).toStdString().data(), -1, wString, 4096);
                LPCWSTR lc = wString;
                if (WBEM_S_NO_ERROR == spclsObj.get()->Get(lc, 0, &vtProp, 0, 0))
                {
                    if (std::get<2>(k) == "string")
                        records.enqueue(QPair<QString, QString>(std::get<1>(k), QString::fromStdWString(vtProp.bstrVal)));
                    else if (std::get<2>(k) == "int")
                        records.enqueue(QPair<QString, QString>(std::get<1>(k), QString::number(vtProp.intVal)));
                    VariantClear(&vtProp);
                }
                delete[] wString;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Используй [QString::fromWCharArray](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#fromWCharArray) для голых `wchar_t *` типов как `BSTR`
[QString::fromStdWString](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#fromStdWString) стоит использовать непосредственно для `std::wstring` во избежание проблем с конвертацией типов

```
records.enqueue(QPair<QString, QString>(k.second, QString::fromWCharArray(vtProp.bstrVal)));
```